# Node.js MySQL concurrency deadlocks

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures, concurrency, deadlock

I have a node.js application which is importing lots of data into a MySQL database. I have recently changed the primary key of the table to an auto incrementing integer. Since making this change, MySQL is giving me a large quantity of deadlocks and subsequently not importing all the data.

> ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Here is my node.js call to a MySQL stored procedure. This is called many times, concurrently:

```
pool.query(
    "CALL AddItineraryDayLocation(?,?,?,?)",
    [itineraryId, location.name, location.longitude, location.latitude],
    function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) 
            console.log(error);    
    }
);
```

Here's the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `AddItineraryDayLocation`(
    IN tourItineraryId int,
    IN name VARCHAR(50),
    IN longitude decimal(12,8),
    IN latitude decimal(12,8)
)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO
        touritinerarylocation (`tourItineraryId`, `name`, `longitude`, `latitude`)
    VALUES
        (tourItineraryId, name, longitude, latitude)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        `tourItineraryId` = tourItineraryId,
        `name` = name,
        `longitude` = longitude,
        `latitude` = latitude;

END
```

and the table:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `touritinerarylocation` (
  `tourItineraryLocationId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tourItineraryId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(12,8) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(12,8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tourItineraryLocationId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tourItineraryId_longitude_latitude_UNIQUE` (`tourItineraryId`,`longitude`,`latitude`),
  KEY `fk_tourItineraryLocation_tourItinerary_idx` (`tourItineraryId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tourItineraryLocation_tourItinerary` FOREIGN KEY (`tourItineraryId`) REFERENCES `touritinerary` (`tourItineraryId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11674 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I've tried adding a transaction to the stored procedure, that didn't help. I've also tried wrapping the node.js query in a while loop to attempt to retry the operation but I had problems with scoping and the code just seemed to grind to a halt at the first call of the query (the callback was never hit).

Is there a standard way of dealing with deadlocks with this sort of setup? I've tried searching for similar problems but I've been unable to find anything relevant or useful.

Comment: What indexes does your table have?

Comment: Primary key is `tourItineraryLocationId`. There is a unique index on `tourItineraryId`, `longitude` and `latitude`. There is also a foreign key on `tourItineraryId.

Comment: Added create statement to the question for further clarity.

Comment: I suggest instead of using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, you should use normal `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and remember to wrap them all inside a transaction